# Why does this C++ member initializer list not work?

Tags: c++, string, initialization

In *C++ in Plain English, Second Edition* (1999), there's a section in the book that says an "=" can be used to do initialization while calling the right constructor. Like given a class `CStr` and a constructor `CStr(char*)`, the book says this:

> Similarly, the final declaration calls the constructor CStr(char*):
>
> ```
> CStr name3 = "Jane Doe";
> ```

I wanted to try the same thing with a `std::string` constructor. Part of my test code is this:

```
using namespace std;
class CStr {
private:
    string name;
public:
    CStr(string s): name(s) {}
};

int main() {
    CStr name3 = "Jane Doe";
}
```

When I compile, however, I get an error in the name3 initialization:

> "conversion from 'const char [9]' to non-scalar type 'CStr' requested".

Why didn't initializing CStr::name to a string s = "Jane Doe" work? An string test like `string nameTest{"Jane Doe"};` worked, so I thought this would work too. Maybe the book's old (it's the only book I have right now), but I'm thinking the error's more on my part.

Comment: Btw, C++ changed quite a bit since '99. Two new standards that added a heap of new features and removed some of the obsolete once were released since then.

Comment: Still have a copy of that book on my desk, actually. Very useful book in it's time as a quick reference for the C standard library.

Comment: BTW, the times where you could use a string literal with a `CStr(char *)` constructor are gone. String literals are no longer convertible to `char *` type, only to `const char *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your book is old, but basically right<sup>[1]</sup>. Note that `"Jane Doe"` is not `std::string`, it's `const char[9]` (and could decay to `const char*`). So for `CStr name3 = "Jane Doe";`, two user-defined conversion is needed, (i.e. `const char*` -> `std::string` and `std::string` -> `CStr`), which is not allowed in one [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).

This also demonstrates that if `CStr`'s construct takes `const char*` as its parameter, `CStr name3 = "Jane Doe";` would work fine, because only one user-defined conversion is needed for it.

You could reduce one by adding explicit conversion:

```
CStr name3 = std::string("Jane Doe");
```

or use [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14) directly, which is of type `std::string`:

```
CStr name3 = "Jane Doe"s;
```

---

> Why didn't initializing CStr::name to a string s = "Jane Doe" work? An string test like `string nameTest{"Jane Doe"};` worked, so I thought this would work too.

Your question is not clear enough, anyway, `std::string nameTest{"Jane Doe"};` works because, (depends on your misunderstandings,) (1) only one implicit conversion (`const char*` -> `std::string` is needed here; (2) `string nameTest{"Jane Doe"};` is direct initialization.

As @LightnessRacesinOrbit commented, [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) (i.e. `CStr name3("Jane Doe")` or `CStr name3{"Jane Doe"}` (since C++11) ) would work fine, while `CStr name3 = "Jane Doe";` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), they're different at some points:

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must
>   produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g.
>   direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the
>   initializer to an argument of T's constructor.
>
> ```
> struct S { S(std::string) {} }; // implicitly convertible from std::string
> S s("abc"); // OK: conversion from const char[4] to std::string
> S s = "abc"; // Error: no conversion from const char[4] to S
> S s = "abc"s; // OK: conversion from std::string to S
> ```

It means, for a copy initialization, the argument `Jane Doe`, which is a `const char*`, has to be converted to `CStr` directly; because two user-defined conversion is needed the code is rejected. For a direct initialization, it's fine to convert `Jane Doe` (`const char*`) to the argument of `CStr`'s constructor, i.e. `std::string` firstly, then `CStr::CStr(std::string)` will be invoked to construct the object.

---

[1] `"Jane Doe"` is a c-style [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) which is const, from C++11 it's illegal to assign it to `char*`, e.g.

```
char * pc = "Jane Doe";         // illegal
const char * pcc = "Jane Doe";  // fine
```

Comment: Or `CStr name3("Jane Doe")` or `CStr name3{"Jane Doe"}`

Comment: Your answer is good but the missing piece of the puzzle is that this is one of the ways copy-initialisation differs from other kinds.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How is OP misunderstanding is not clear enough to me; anyway I tried to add relevant explanations.

Comment: @songyuanyao That clears everything, thanks. Your notes on the conversions are really descriptive. I didn't think about the error much, I did a quick assumption that "Jane Doe" was `std::string`. My confusion was this: I thought that  "Jane Doe" was `std::string`. I tried `string nameTest{"Jane Doe"}`. My thought was, "This worked. I'm basically doing `string nameTest = "Jane Doe"`. Therefore, in the constructor, why wouldn't `string s = "Jane Doe"` work? I see now that "Jane Doe" is not `std::string`, and therefore there were no matching constructors to begin with.